# Is there a way to add product quantity to a 'share wishlist' email template?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to add the product quantity to the 'share wishlist' email, but I am not getting product quantity.

```html
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($block->getWishlistItems() as $item): ?>
    <?php /* @var $item \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item */ ?>
    <?php /* @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
    <?php $_product = $item->getProduct(); ?>
    <tr>
    <td class="item-info">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU'); ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku($_product)) ?></p>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty">
        I WANT TO DISPLAY QTY HERE
    </td>
    <td class="item-price">
         <?php 
         setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');
         $amount = money_format('%(#1n',$item->getProduct()->getData('price'));
         echo $amount;
         ?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getEscapedDescription($item) ?>
    </td>
    <tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

This allowed me to use product quantity in an email template.

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQty($item) * 1 ?>
```

Comment: Is possible multiple wishlists like Amazon?

Comment: @Rathinam yes, magento 2 is allowing to have multiple wishlist.